# Vue lifecycle events triggers on every route

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

According to the documentation https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram all events from `beforeCreate` till `mounted` should be called once. But they are being triggered on every vue-router path navigated

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App },
  created: function () {
    this.$http.get('/user/get').then(response => {
      if (response.data.error) {
        console.log(response.data.error)
      } else {
        User.set(response.data.user)
        router.go('/dashboard')   // this does force looping
      }
    }, response => {
      router.go('/')
    })
  }
})
```

This is App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <topmenu></topmenu>
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Topmenu from '@/components/topmenu'

export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    topmenu: Topmenu
  }
}
</script>
```

The Router.vue

```
Vue.use(Router)

let route = new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'Home',
      component: Home
    },
    {
      path: '/user/signup',
      name: 'Signup',
      component: Signup
    },
    {
      path: '/dashboard',
      name: 'Dashboard',
      component: Dashboard
    }
  ]
})
route.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.path.match(/^(\/|\/signup)$/)) {
    return next()
  }
  if (User.valid()) {
    return next()
  }
  route.push('/')
})
export default route
```

How to avoid this events from being triggered on every route switched?

Comment: you shouldn't need to specify a template or components in the config of your root Vue instance. That's maybe messing things up

Comment: there is no template in the main,js (first script). Anyway once template created and mounted only `router-view` component updates content.

Comment: You have `template: '<App/>', components: { App },` in the parameter object for the Vue root instance. That's what I'm saying is probably messing things up

Comment: I can understand if it was once more, but this happening continuously. With routing I'm changing content of the component `<router-view></router-view>` only. Why this forces all events of the parent component to be triggered?